# NextJS 13 Error / Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

**Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.
**
Can you tell me why the error occurs?

```
// layout.tsx
import Layout from "./components/common/Layout";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Layout>{children}</Layout>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// Layout.tsx

"use client";

import React, { useState, ReactNode } from "react";
import Nav from "@app/components/common/Nav";
import { Global, css } from "@emotion/react";
import { PageContextProvider } from "store/pageContext";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            staleTime: 5000,
          },
        },
      })
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Global styles={reset} />
        <PageContextProvider>
          <Nav />
          <div>{children}</div>
        </PageContextProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// pageContext.tsx

"use client";

import React, { createContext, useState, useRef } from "react";

interface PageContextType {
  currentPage: number;
  setCurrentPage: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
  sectionsRef: React.MutableRefObject<(HTMLElement | null)[]>;
}

export const PageContext = createContext<PageContextType>({
  currentPage: 0,
  setCurrentPage: () => {},
  sectionsRef: {} as React.MutableRefObject<(HTMLElement | null)[]>,
});

export const PageContextProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(0);
  const sectionsRef = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([]);

  return (
    <PageContext.Provider value={{ currentPage, setCurrentPage, sectionsRef }}>
      {children}
    </PageContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I want to use the layout.tsx file as a server component and add metadata, but if I don't use "use client" in the layout file, an error occurs. Do you know anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the init of `QueryClient` into a separate component (which will have `use client`), import it in your Layout component and remove the `use client` there.
This way your layout component will be a server component.

Comment: @JongsungJung did it work? Please mark as solved if it did.